# Obfuscation of assemblies without 3rd party tools

Tags: c#, build, obfuscation

There are some 3rd party tools out there for Obfuscation of assemblies!
Take a look at this one :
[Using SmartAssembly with MSBuild](http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SA6/Using+SmartAssembly+with+MSBuild)

How can i write a simple class for obfuscate my assembly and i do n't want to use any 3rd party tools such [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/)?

**OR**

How can i import [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) as a dll to my project and use it for my purpose?

**EDIT : What is my goal?**
I have some passwords in my c# codes and i just want to hide them from reverse engineering!

Comment: This is quite a broad question. However depending on how much your code should be encrypted you may start off by simply building a map with all the names that you already used and replace any member/param/... owith a name that is not containined there.

Comment: If you have passwords in clear text in your code, then obfuscation isn't going to hide them.  You actually should use encryption for that.

Comment: This is definitly a XY-problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not stored security-information within your source-code. Write them to XML or any other external datasource, encrpyt this information and then you won´t need any obfuscation.

However obfuscation won´t hanlde this case as it simply replaces the names of variables and parameters, not their actual values. So if you have something like this:

```
string password = "topsecret";
```

Obfuscator would simply replace this by something similar to:

```
var a="topsecret";
```

To shorten this discussion a bit: there is no way that gives you absolute savety to avoid that anyone can get your user-credentials. All you can do is to make it more difficult to do so and to hope that the "attacker" gives up before he or she succeeds. So in most situations ecrpyting the password externally should do what you need.

Comment: You know : encryption and decryption methods are visible in reverse too. so encrypted values simply can be decrypt. I checked SmartAssembly and it totaly hides those passwords. But How?

Comment: Sure, encrpytion is visible as long as the encrpytion-key is it. However even IF SmartAssembly would do something similar I dount it couln´t be reverted.

Comment: So there is no way to hide encrpytion-key!  But using with SA there is no way to decrypt.

Comment: @MoonLight, SA obfuscation result can be simply decrypted if you know how to. Read this article for more info, https://obfuscar.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=What%20It%20Does String encryption is almost useless, though it does help confuse at least some. And yes, I currently run the Obfuscar project.

Comment: @Lex Li, What is your suggestion? I don't think any body can reverse obfuscated SA (Using all it's options)!!

Comment: @MoonLight, this answer already gives you a few options. Revise your design to use external storage which can be encrypted and you can avoid embed passwords in code. If you check other software (your web browsers for example), such an approach is widely used.

Comment: "store it in XML" but then where do you hide the password for the potentially encrypted XML? You see, this then starts the endless cycle of "where to hide that password".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at opensource projects like [Obfuscar](https://obfuscar.codeplex.com/) - it's far from a trivial task

Comment: Thanks for recommending Obfuscar, but if you read the question carefully you will see that this is far from a valid answer. Obfuscation cannot prevent secrets from being hunted. Such passwords should never be part of a program.

Comment: @Lex Li, you are right. But how can we hide secret data without encryption and decryption?

Comment: @MoonLight You can't. Period.

Comment: @LexLi - sorry, I answered the question in its original format...

Answer (score 0):

This is the fabled "how do I hide passwords in my sourcecode" question. The simple answer: You can't. Period. Anything you do can be undone by someone with enough time and energy. You can, however, make it more difficult for the would be hacker. Some things you could do is password hashing, and then store that hash in the source code. That means the hacker would need to have knowledge of hashing algorithms to reverse it or figure out what it was. I have learned that it is not worth your time though. If someone wants to crack your program there is simply nothing you can do to stop them. It's the horrifying truth of programming.